# How to use DataArray values ​as list indexes?

Tags: python, expression

First of all, I'm sorry for the not very explicit title, I just couldn't find anything better. I have a silly question, but I've been stuck on it for hours.

Basically I have an `xarray` `DataSet` in which is a data variable called `data_index` with integers from 0 to 3. These integers correspond to the indexes of a list. I would like to add a data variable to my `DataSet` that matches the list value for the index given by the `data_index` variable.

Here is an exemple of what I have :

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.Dataset()
ds["data_index"] = (("x", "y"), [[0, 1], [2, 3]] )

list = ["a", "b" , "c", "d"]
```

I'd like to add a data variable called `data` to the dataset ds by picking the value of the list that correspond to the index data_index. Would be something like :
`ds["data"] = list[ds["data_index"]]`

My `DataSet` is much bigger than that. The real dimensions are `(x: 30001, y: 20001)`. But the variable `data_index` contains only integers from 0 to 3 and the list is also 4-element long.

I'm sure there is an easy way to do it but I just can't find it. Do you have any leads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the result, you can use the `isel` method provided by `xarray`. Allowing you to index a dataset along with a particular dimension using `int` based indexing.

**Edit**:

Your right. I've actually added an additional library called `numpy` to help with reshaping the resulting data array.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

ds = xr.Dataset()
ds["data_index"] = (("x", "y"), [[0, 1], [2, 3]])

my_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

data_values = np.array([my_list[idx] for idx in ds["data_index"].values.flatten()])
data_reshaped = data_values.reshape(ds["data_index"].shape)

ds["data"] = xr.DataArray(data_reshaped, dims=("x", "y"))

print(ds)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This solution almost works, but the dimensions of [my_list[idx] for idx in ds["data_index"].values.flatten()] doesn't match the dimensions ("x", "y"). The shape is flat. Is there a way to reshape the DataArray?

Comment: Ok so this is working:
`ds["data"] = xr.DataArray(np.reshape([my_list[idx] for idx in ds["data_index"].values.flatten()], ds.data_index.shape), dims=ds.data_index.dims)`
But i'm wondering if it is the optimal solution for large dataset?